# Create TableComponent using template like DevExpress

Tags: c#, blazor

I'd like to create a TableComponent which will be works like DevExpress library, where we can do something like this code belowe.
I pondering how ChildComponents in this code send value of params to ParentComponent (DxDataGrid)?
I was trying to send reference to parent via cascadingvalue but it doesn't work.
I was thinking about EventCallBack but in this code belowe we don't assign any function and i don't want to do this too...
Have You any idea how it works?

Thank's for any help!

```
<DxDataGrid DataAsync="@ForecastService.GetForecastAsync"
            PageSize="5"
            RowRemovingAsync="@OnRowRemoving"
            RowUpdatingAsync="@OnRowUpdating"
            RowInsertingAsync="@OnRowInserting"
            InitNewRow="@OnInitNewRow"
            CssClass="mw-1100">
    <DxDataGridCommandColumn Width="150px" />
    <DxDataGridDateEditColumn Field="@nameof(WeatherForecast.Date)" DisplayFormat="D" EditorFormat="d" EditorDisplayFormat="D" />
    <DxDataGridColumn Field="@nameof(WeatherForecast.Forecast)" Caption="Forecast" Width="150px" />
    <DxDataGridSpinEditColumn Field="@nameof(WeatherForecast.TemperatureC)" Caption="@("Temp. (\x2103)")" TextAlignment="DataGridTextAlign.Left"
                              Width="150px" />
    <DxDataGridComboBoxColumn Field="@nameof(WeatherForecast.CloudCover)" Caption="Cloud Cover" DataAsync="@ForecastService.GetCloudCoverAsync"
                              TextAlignment="DataGridTextAlign.Left" Width="150px" />
    <DxDataGridCheckBoxColumn Field="@nameof(WeatherForecast.Precipitation)" Caption="Precipitation" Width="100px" />
</DxDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was thinking about EventCallBack but in this code belowe we don't assign any function and i don't want to do this too.

You don't have to set the `EventCallBack` yourself in the `DxDataGrid`. It is probably done internally.

The following is only a guesswork based on my knowledge in Blazor, and two minutes I've spend in perusing the DevExpress library.

Let's try to understand what is `<DxDataGridComboBoxColumn/>`

I guess it is a component that represents a DataGrid column that hosts ComboBox controls in its cells.

```
`<DxComboBox/>` (not appearing in your code) is I believe a component 
representing a ComboBox control. Thus, I guess that `<DxDataGridComboBoxColumn/>` is the parent component of `<DxComboBox/>`. Sound reasonable, no?
```

Now, I made some search and found this code:

```
<DxComboBox Data="@(new List<string>() { "In stock", "Sold out" })"
                        Value="@(((bool)((CellEditContext)context).CellValue) ? "In stock" : "Sold out" )"
                        ValueChanged="@((string newCellValue) => ((CellEditContext)context).OnChanged(newCellValue == "In stock"))">
            </DxComboBox>
```

What do I see here ? The how the `DxComboBox` gets its data (from a List instantiated in-line. There is also two attributes: `Value` and `ValueChanged`
The `Value` attribute represents the variable the `DxComboBox` is bound to, while
the `ValueChanged` attribute represents the method that should be called when the user select a value from the `DxComboBox` (Html select element). This method is called to notify the parent component of `DxComboBox` that a value has changed, and it has to re-render to reflect this change. Note that the underlying type of  that method is EventCallBack.

My advise to you is to go to the docs and or web sites like `chrissainty.com` or blazoruniversity, and learn there more about components, how they communicate with each other, templated components, etc. Learn the basic of Blazor, and one day you'll be able to create such components yourself. There is a code sample in the docs how to create templated components in the form of a table. Start from there and go on...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DataGrid from Blazorise](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/). You can look at the source code on GitHub if you want to roll your own